# Fastlane: No certificate for team '...' matching "...". - How to specify the right team?

Tags: ios, continuous-integration, code-signing, fastlane

In my Fastfile, I can specify my app's `codesigning_identity` and `provisioningProfiles`. However, I always get the following error:

*Code Signing Error: No certificate for team 'ABCDEFG8' matching 'iPhone Developer: My Certificate' found:  Select a different signing certificate for CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY, a team that matches your selected certificate, or switch to automatic provisioning.*

The problem is, that the team (here: ABCDEFG8) is the WRONG team, and not the one that contains the certificate I wanna use. How can I specify the project team for a specific certificate?

Comment: Can you post the contents of your Fastfile? - You may need to check that your team id is set correctly in your project settings in Xcode also.

Comment: Were you able to resolve this issue?